# Next JS router multiple accounts off query string

Tags: next.js13, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I have url `/user/query/{ACCOUNT_NUMBER}` for single account number as parameter.  In NextJS, I am using useRouter and getting params from url.

How can we get  multiple account numbers off query string with NextJS router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is how Next.js handles dynamic routes.

If your URL looks something like this: **[www.example.com/1/2/3](http://www.example.com/1/2/3)** You can have access to the numbers **1**, **2**, and **3** by calling the **useRouter hook**.

What you'll have to do is change your file name to something like this **[...accountNumber].tsx**

Let's say your file is located at **pages/account/[...accountNumber].tsx**, when you're navigating to /account/1/2/3, Next.js will take every parameter that comes after the **account/** and put it in **router.query.accountNumber**

```js
        const router = useRouter()

        console.log(router.query.accountNumber) // ['1', '2', '3']
```

You can read more about how Next.js handles dynamic routes [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes)